# GATHER_PLAN_STATISTICS does does not generate basic plan statistics

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

all,

I am learning to tune query now, when I ran the following:

```
select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ * from emp;

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display(FORMAT=>'ALLSTATS LAST'));
```

The result always says:

> - Warning: basic plan statistics not available. These are only collected when:
>
>   - hint 'gather_plan_statistics' is used for the statement or
>   - parameter 'statistics_level' is set to 'ALL', at session or system level

I tried the `alter session set statistics_level = ALL;` too in sqlplus, but that did not change anything in the result.

Could anyone please let me know what I might have missed?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Same here. Did you solve the question?

Answer (score 11):

[DISPLAY Function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_xplan.htm#CACICEDJ) displays a content of PLAN_TABLE generated (filled) by [EXPLAIN PLAN FOR](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9010.htm#SQLRF01601) command. So you can use it to generate and display an (theoretical) plan using EXPLAIN PLAN FOR command, for example in this way:

```
create table emp as select * from all_objects;

explain plan for
select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ count(*) from emp where object_id between 100 and 150;

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display );

Plan hash value: 2083865914
 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |     1 |     5 |   351   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE    |      |     1 |     5 |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |    12 |    60 |   351   (1)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   2 - filter("OBJECT_ID"<=150 AND "OBJECT_ID">=100)
```

---

/*+ gather_plan_statistics */ hint does not save data into PLAN_TABLE, but it stores execution statistics in V$SQL_PLAN performance view.
To display these data you can use a method described here: https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/dbms_xplan#gather_plan_statistics_hint, but this not always work, because you must execute the second command immediately after the SQL query.
The better method is to query V$SQL view to obtain SQL_ID of the query, and then use [DISPLAY_CURSOR](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db121/ARPLS/d_xplan.htm#ARPLS70136) function, for example in this way:

```
select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ count(*) from emp where object_id between 100 and 150;

select sql_id, plan_hash_value, child_number, executions, fetches, cpu_time, elapsed_time, physical_read_requests, physical_read_bytes
from v$sql s
where sql_fulltext like 'select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ count(*)%from emp%'
  and sql_fulltext not like '%from v$sql' ;

SQL_ID        PLAN_HASH_VALUE CHILD_NUMBER EXECUTIONS    FETCHES   CPU_TIME ELAPSED_TIME PHYSICAL_READ_REQUESTS PHYSICAL_READ_BYTES
------------- --------------- ------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ------------ ---------------------- -------------------
9jjm288hx7buz      2083865914            0          1          1      15625        46984                     26            10305536
```

The above query returns `SQL_ID=9jjm288hx7buz` and `CHILD_NUMBER=0`(child number is just a cursor number). Use these values to query the colledted plan:

```
SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR('9jjm288hx7buz', 0, 'ALLSTATS'));

SQL_ID  9jjm288hx7buz, child number 0
-------------------------------------
select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ count(*) from emp where object_id 
between 100 and 150
 
Plan hash value: 2083865914
 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |      2 |        |      2 |00:00:00.05 |   10080 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE    |      |      2 |      1 |      2 |00:00:00.05 |   10080 |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |      2 |     47 |     24 |00:00:00.05 |   10080 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   2 - filter(("OBJECT_ID"<=150 AND "OBJECT_ID">=100))
```

Comment: Thank you for the carefully crafted answer, I learned  a lot!

Comment: @wolφi if you like this answer then please [upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) it, thank you.

Comment: Done so a long time ago :-)

Answer (score 7):

If all you ran were the two statements in your question:

> ```
> select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ * from emp;
>
> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display(FORMAT=>'ALLSTATS LAST'));
> ```

Then I think your problem is your use of `DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY`.  The way you are using it, you are printing the plan of the last statement you explained, not the last statement you executed.  And "explain" will not execute the query, so it will not benefit from a `gather_plan_statistics` hint.

This works for me in 12c:

```
select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ count(*) from dba_objects;

SELECT *
FROM   TABLE (DBMS_XPLAN.display_cursor (null, null, 'ALLSTATS LAST'));
```

i.e., `display_cursor` instead of just `display`.

Comment: Definitely -- it is very cool.  Though, the modern GUI tools like SQL\*Developer have many of the same features now.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I found the following explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388837/dbms-xplan-display-cursor-vs-explain-plan-if-not-using-gather-plan-statistics-hi

Comment: Do you think I should clarify my answer or just mark the question as a duplicate?

Comment: No, not at all, please leave your answer. I don't know what would happen to the bounty...

Answer (score 6):

What I leared from the answers so far:

When a query is parsed, the optimizer estimates how many rows are produced during each step of the query plan. Sometimes it is neccessary to check how good the prediction was. If the estimates are off by more than a order of magnitude, this might lead to the wrong plan being used.

To compare estimated and actual numbers, the following steps are necessary:

1. You need read access to `V$SQL_PLAN`, `V$SESSION` and `V$SQL_PLAN_STATISTICS_ALL`. These privileges are included in the `SELECT_CATALOG` role. [(source)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_xplan.htm#ARPLS70124)
2. Switch on statistics gathering, either by

   `ALTER SESSION SET STATISTICS_LEVEL = ALL;`

   or by using the hint `/*+ gather_plan_statistics */` in the query.

   There seems to be a certain performance overhead.
   See for instance Jonathan's [blog](https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2007/11/25/gather_plan_statistics/).
3. Run the query. You'll need to find it later, so it's best to include an arbitrary hint:

   `SELECT /*+ gather_plan_statistics HelloAgain */ * FROM scott.emp;`

   `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT ...` is not sufficient, as it will only create the estimates without running the actual query.

   Furthermore, as @Matthew suggested (thanks!), it is important to actually fetch all rows. Most GUIs will show only the first 50 rows or so. In SQL Developer, you can use the shortcut [ctrl+End](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/05/oracle-sql-developer-fetching-sql-statement-result-sets/) in the query result window.
4. Find the query in the cursor cache and note it's `SQL_ID`:

   `SELECT sql_id, child_number, sql_text 
      FROM V$SQL 
     WHERE sql_text LIKE '%HelloAgain%';`

   `dbqbqxp9srftn  0  SELECT /*+ gather_plan...`
5. Format the result:

   `SELECT * 
      FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR('dbqbqxp9srftn',0,'ALLSTATS LAST'));`

Steps 4. and 5. can be combined:

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM v$sql s, 
       TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR(s.sql_id, s.child_number)) x 
 WHERE s.sql_text LIKE '%HelloAgain%';
```

The result shows the **estimated** rows (`E-Rows`) and the **actual** rows (`A-Rows`):

```
SQL_ID  dbqbqxp9srftn, child number 0
-------------------------------------
SELECT /*+ gather_plan_statistics HelloAgain */ * FROM scott.emp

Plan hash value: 3956160932

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |      1 |        |     14 |00:00:00.01 |       6 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |      1 |     14 |     14 |00:00:00.01 |       6 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Nice summary.  The only thing I would add is to step #3.  You need to run the query _and_ fetch all the results.  Sometimes, with tools like SQL*Navigator, developers forget to fetch to the end before looking at `DBMS_XPLAN`.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak thanks for the hint, that is very important indeed!

Answer (score 0):

ALLSTATS LAST starts working after you ran the statement twice.