# Difference on explain plan and gather_plan_statistics

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-execution-plan

Can anyone tell me when we should use gather_plan_statistics hint or when we should use explain plan. What is the actual purpose of gather_plan_statistics hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it looks confusing but is quite simple:

- Explain plan looks at a query and creates an theoretical execution plan.
- Gather_plan_statistics instructs the optimizer to keep notes during the actual execution, to be able to compare the theory with reality.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32823223/gather-plan-statistics-does-does-not-generate-basic-plan-statistics) for details.

Answer (score 1):

An even better option is the generate a SQL Monitor report. SQL's are automatically monitored, so no need to re-run with the hint. The SQL Monitor report provides far more information than gether_plan_statistics. 
Finally, the stats in gather_plan_statistics are not reliable when executing parallel queries.