# Slow Performance in Transferring and Updating Records

Tags: oracle

I'm dealing with a large Oracle database with a table named pos_data that holds over 450 million point of sale records. I'm trying to optimize the performance of transferring records within a specific date range to another table called pos_current.

Currently, I've attempted to use an INSERT INTO ... SELECT statement with an APPEND hint for around 250 million records after applying a date range filter. Surprisingly, this operation is taking more than 1 hour, and I'm looking for suggestions on how to speed up this process.

Additionally, after completing the transfer, I need to update the manuf_nbr column in pos_current by joining the prod_nbr column to the product table, which contains the manufacturer numbers. I initially used a simple MERGE statement for this purpose, but it was running for over 5 hours before I decided to cancel it.

```
MERGE INTO pos_curr pc
USING product sp ON (sp.prod_nbr = pc.prod_nbr)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET pc.manuf_nbr = nvl(sp.manuf_nbr,'~');
```

I have index on prod_nbr column of both tables.
Would using a cursor for the update provide better performance in this scenario, or are there alternative strategies to consider?

Thanks in advance for any insights or recommendations!

Comment: Direct path writes with `INSERT /*+ APPEND */...`, or even better, a direct path parallel write with `INSERT /*+ APPEND PARALLEL(8) */ ...` should improve performance. But APPEND hints can fail for multiple reasons. Generate an execution plan using the `/*+ GATHER_PLAN_STATISTICS */` hint as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50593217/409172), to see the real plan (and hopefully the operation "LOAD AS SELECT" which implies direct path worked), the "Note" section (which describes why hints failed), and the actual times and cardinalities (which tells with operation was slow and why).

Comment: @JonHeller sure I will check that. Do you think if I use "BULK COLLECT INTO" with 100k batch size to merge would give me better results?

Comment: No, it's almost always faster to use SQL instead of PL/SQL. For the MERGE, you should also check the execution plan, and maybe ensure that the statistics are up to date, if a large percentage of the table frequently changes.

Comment: What logs have you examined to see what is slow?  For example, have you looked at the query plan for the `insert ... select` statement?  Should the "date range filter" allow Oracle to use partition pruning to scan a limited number of partitions (if the underlying table is partitioned)?  Does the query plan show that Oracle is actually doing partition pruning?  Is the data volume such that Oracle could efficiently use an index on the date range?  Does the query plan show that Oracle is actually using that index?  What sorts of wait events are you seeing?

Comment: @JustinCave Insert into statement is transferring data from one to another table. No join involved. Right now the table is not partitioned & there is no index on crt_ts column, on which there is no index created.

Comment: OK.  So then the query is doing a table scan of the underlying table.  How large is the table you are doing a full scan on?  What sorts of wait events are you seeing?  Do those wait events indicate that the slowness comes from trying to scan the source table or from inserting data into the destination table?  Are you doing this in a maintenance window where you can use all of the system's resources?  Or are you trying to do this without degrading performance for other users in the system?

Comment: I need to do some research on trying to find out details about the metrics you mentioned. But yes, there are 12 columns & 200 million records that needs to be transferred. If you have any tips and tricks or any documentation I can follow on handling such huge volume of data, it would be helpful. Because my next operation is set flag to each of the record based on whether or not the Id column is present in another table. both compare columns are indexed & I am trying to use merge operation just like one in my question. It took 59 minutes to complete the operation.

Comment: @Visha If the MERGE is only for the newly inserted rows, it is probably faster to avoid the MERGE by replacing it with a join in the INSERT statement. Combining operations is important for optimal performance. (However, combining operations also means the individual steps become more complicated and therefore harder to debug and tune.)

Comment: @JonHeller yes. I realized that after comparing the total execution time of insert + merge against single insert with inner join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, ensure that you force a full table scan with parallelism on the source table. You don't want indexes to be used here unless the date range is very, very tiny. If it is partitioned by this date even better; if by another date, try to see if you can apply another filter on the partition key to eliminate older partitions, that will greatly help by reducing I/O. If the table is not partitioned, consider partitioning it by the date column you are using. That will really help speed things up.

Second, combine the insert with the `manuf_nbr` denormalization. Updates (and a merge update is an update) are *very* expensive at large data volumes. Inserts, especially direct path (and even more so with nologging, if that's permissible), are a *fraction* of the cost. You really want to get any changes you need done at insert time.

Third, ensure you are in fact getting PDML (parallel DML). It has to be explicitly enabled and hinted. Make sure there are no triggers, no enabled foreign key constraints, etc.. that disqualify PDML, and generate an execution plan that shows the PQ coordinator above the load step.

Overall it should look something like this:

```
ALTER SESSION ENABLE PARALLEL DML;

INSERT /*+ append parallel(pc,16) */ INTO pos_cur pc
      (col1,
       col2,
       col3,
       col4,
       manuf_nbr)
       (SELECT /*+ parallel(16) full(pd) use_hash(p pd) */ 
               pd.col1,
               pd.col2,
               pd.col3,
               pd.col4,
               NVL(p.manuf_nbr,'~') manuf_nbr
          FROM pos_data pd ,
               product p
         WHERE pd.datecol > :cutoff
           AND pd.prod_nbr = p.prod_nbr(+));
```

Consult with your DBA about an appropriate DOP (degree of parallelism). Your hardware might not support 16, or it may allow for much more.

In the end, you must consult database metrics (like ASH data or a SQL Monitor report) to determine what an operation is doing and narrow down where it's spending its time so that you can come up with strategies to address those bottlenecks. But the above is what I'd start with.

Comment: 1) Date range is always 6 months & table currently not partitioned. I will propose this for future 2) Added manuf_nbr as part of initial load. 3) using append hint improved performance. I need to check with parallel hint. I disable all constraints on the table before insert starts. I will check with my DBA on the metrics you mentioned here. Thanks for detailed answer.

Comment: @visha, If using pdml, you need only disable foreign key constraints. null, check and PK/UK can remain.

Comment: yes, I was disabling foreign keys but not null checks. I will disable null checks as well & compare performance.